# Deltaspike ConfigProperty working for EJB but not for simple bean in Wildfly 8.1

Tags: ejb, wildfly, deltaspike

I am using Apache Deltaspike 1.0 to inject properties into the beans within my application. I am curious whether the observation I made indicates a bug or not. I created a simple managed bean that was annotated with @ApplicationScoped and everything worked fine. Then I activated Wildfly's sub-deployment isolation mechanism (see [the relevant section in the docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly)). Afterwards, the properties are no longer injected.

However, if I "promote" my managed bean to an EJB with @Singleton @Startup the properties are injected again. I actually don't need most of my beans to be EJBs but I did not find any other way at the moment.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Sven

Comment: For anyone interested in the solution to this problem: https://community.jboss.org/thread/242945

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not directly related to Wildfly 8.1, but to the combination with camel-cdi. I explained it in the Wildfly forums: https://community.jboss.org/thread/242945